# MS Access- Join Tables where a column in one table is between two others

Tags: ms-access, inner-join

I have two tables

The first has all the transactions that are made from a network of shops.
It has the columns `Branch Code`, `CashierNumber` (Which is the teller spot where the transaction was made), `Date_of_Transaction`, `Transaction_Time`.

The second has data of ticket queue.
It has the columns `Branch_code`, `Ticket_Number`, `Cashier_Number`, `Date`, `Ticket_call_Time`, `End_of_Service_Time`.

I want to find how many transactions each ticket makes. The logic is that the transaction time for each cashier, branch, date must in the transaction table be between the `ticket_call_time` and `end_of_service_time` for each cashier, branch, date in the ticketqueuetable.

my query is:

```
SELECT transaction_table.*,
       ticketqueuetable.*,
  from transaction_table
    inner JOIN ticketqueuetable
      ON ticketqueuetable.branch_code=ticketqueuetable.branch_code, 
         ticketqueuetable.DATE=ticketqueuetable.DATE 
         ticketqueuetable.cashiernumber=ticketqueuetable.cashiernumber 
         ticketqueuetable.transactiontime>=ticketqueuetable.call_time 
         ticketqueuetable.transactiontime<=ticketqueuetable.end_of_service_time
```

The result I get gives me each ticket many times (others two, others 3, others one) but then besides each ticket it adds the same transaction many times, not the combination of ticket and transaction.

Can you help me?

Hope you understand.

Comment: Since this is not a valid access query, I doubt that you are getting any result. Superfluous comma at the end of the selecion list. Missing ANDs in join condition. It seems the ticket number is missing in the first table.

Comment: It has ands, I couldn't just think that I get results. Do u have a solution with ands?

Comment: The query should be like this:
`SELECT transaction_table.*,
       ticketqueuetable.*
  from transaction_table
    inner JOIN ticketqueuetable
      ON ticketqueuetable.branch_code=ticketqueuetable.branch_code AND
         ticketqueuetable.DATE=ticketqueuetable.DATE AND
         ticketqueuetable.cashiernumber=ticketqueuetable.cashiernumber AND
         ticketqueuetable.transactiontime>=ticketqueuetable.call_time AND
         ticketqueuetable.transactiontime<=ticketqueuetable.end_of_service_time`.
I don't see the `AND`s in your query.

Comment: My friend ok, i am sorry. Guess that the  query I wrote has ANDs. I had used them. I just didn't write them. I should. I didn't copy, I just wrote it again. Can you find the reason for not getting exactly the results I want? Please rerea my question and gues it has ANDS. Thanks a lot

Comment: Probably because you should also have a ticket number in the first table and also join on that one. Otherwise you might be mixing different ticket numbers.

Comment: Edit question to post examples of source data and desired output and to show your EXACT sql statement.